# What are the meanings of the two line numbers in the Event Listeners section of Chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I am trying to debug an mousedown event in javascript. The Event Listeners panel in Chrome developer tools shows two line numbers. The first line number is in blue on the top right. (742 in the picture). I assume that this number is the first line of the function that handles the mousedown event. But what is the "line number" shown in the expanding menus for the mousedown event? In the picture the "line number" is 834. How is this different from the link to the function, which shows 742? Aside from the fact that each has a different number: what does each one mean?

[image]

**Edit** I am using brunch, which uses javascript source maps. So maybe that is part of what is going on.

Comment: Have you checked what's at those lines in the source file?

Comment: Comparing several examples: 'lineNumber: #' marks the first line of the function that handles the specific event. And in all those examples lineNumber was the same as 'file: #' number.

Answer (score 0):

On current picture, I think line 742 mean `mousedown event` is listening at this line in **quo.js** file. And line 834 mean `mousedown event` is listening at this line in current page. Sorry if it's not useful but this is my idea that I want to share. You can see more [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)